# Is there a good way to convert a nutrient powder (i.e. green drinks) into a low calorie candy?

Tags: candy, powder

I don't like putting powder into my water bottle, because I have trouble getting it washed out, and don't like to use my water cup, so I'm wondering anyone has ever had any luck converting the powder into a hard candy to suck on (i.e. a sucker without a stick) when on the road, because directly into your mouth would make you cough (think cinnamon in the mouth).

Comment: No, but I’ve made extra-strength gatorade popsicles.  That’s not very portable, though.

Comment: It is not clear to me what nutrient powder/green drinks is, perhaps include a link?  If you mean something like [Athletic Greens](https://uk.athleticgreens.com/) then could you not just eat the fruit/vegetables they are made of?

Comment: People have made hard candy out of lots drink-related things (like root beer, green tea, whiskey, etc.). I imagine turning your nutrient powder into hard candy would be much the same process - follow a recipe for normal hard candy, and then add as much or as little of the nutrient powder as you want on the step where you add the flavoring. My only question would be if you can use the powder itself or if you need to make it into a slurry first, but that's a simple matter of experimentation.

Comment: @Abion47 the problem here is the low-calorie aspect. Candy is mostly sugar, structurally, so there isn't much you can do about making it lower-calorie

Comment: @Esther There are ways to get around that limitation. I hear allulose is a good option for making hard candies as long as you don't mind it being less sweet overall. (Maybe even add a drop of honey if you do.) You could also combine a zero-calorie sweetener with something like agar agar to make [a different kind of "hard" candy](https://sugargeekshow.com/recipe/kohakutou-crystal-gummy-candy/).